# AVPlayer with DocumentBrowserView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

Good day.

Someone knows how to transfer the document url to the avplayer if you want to play the video file through DocumentBrowserView

Using documentUrl did not work for me

Comment: what is your mean?
do you want to play local media or online play?

Comment: Better if I can play online video